# How can I make a map to solve in a list of coefficients of an equation?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a list

```
list = {{2, -4, 3, 1, -2}, {2, -3, -4, -1, -2}, {2, -3, 4, -1, -4}}
```

and

```
sol[a_, b_, c_, d_, t_] := 
 Solve[Sqrt[a x^ 2 + b x + c ] == d x + t, x, Real]
```

How can I make a map from `sol` to `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sol];
sol[{a_, b_, c_, d_, t_}] :=  Solve[
    Sqrt[a x^ 2 + b x + c ] == d x + t
    , x 
    , Reals]

list = {
    {2, -4, 3, 1, 2}, 
    {2, -3, -4, -1,2}, 
    {2, -3, 4, -1, 4}, 
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
};
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get out put in the form, e.g `{{\sqrt{2x^2 -4 x + 3}= x+2,x=4-sqrt(17), x = 4 + sqrt(17)}}`?

Comment: @Laurenso Probably you should ask another question, and this time articulate in detail all you need to know.